# Any way to get Jupyter in VSCode to flush the buffer?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter in VSCode doesn't seem to flush the buffer:

```
import time

for i in range (10):  
    print(i, end="\r", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Results in:

```
0123456789
```

but I would expect just:

```
9
```

on completion.

This is VSCode 1.46.1, Python 3.6.1, and the VSCode extension for Python is v2020.6.90262.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer on this extension. I don't think there is any way as I just tried out your repro and it seems that we have a bug here. We're not handling the new prints correctly and our output is different from Jupyter here. We don't track work items on stack overflow, so I filed an issue for this problem on our GitHub here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12673

If you want to track our progress on fixing it just follow it there.